# How to get a dynamic form with php that gets data from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I've got a dropdown menu in a form on my website which is filled with values of a database table which shows all the school-classes of my school. Now I have a second page in which I display all students that are in a database table, wiich are in the selected class, in a form with checkboxes.

My question is now as following:
How can I get these two pages in one together? So that all students of the selected class get displayed when i just select the class in the dropdown menu without pressing the submit button.

My Sourcecode:
1) Code of the website in which the class gets selected:

```
<html>
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$database = "internat_db";

$con=mysqli_connect($db_host, "root", "", $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$klassen = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from klassen");

echo '<form action="schueler_ausgabe.php" method="POST">';
echo '<select name="Klassenwahl">';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($klassen))
  {
    echo "<option value=".$row['Klasse'].">".$row['Klasse']."</option>";
  }  

echo '<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Auswaehlen" />';
echo '</form>';

mysqli_close($con);

?> 
</html>
```

2) Code of the website that displays all students:

```
<html>
    <?php
    $klassenname = $_POST["Klassenwahl"];
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $database = "internat_db";
    $con=mysqli_connect($db_host, "root", "", $database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $zw = "Select vorname, nachname FROM schueler WHERE klasse = '".$klassenname."'";
    $schueler = mysqli_query($con, $zw);

    echo '<form action="" method="POST">';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($schueler))
    {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='schueler' value=".$row['vorname']." ".$row['nachname'].">".$row['vorname']." ".$row['nachname']."";
    echo '<br>';
    } 

    echo '<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Auswaehlen" />';
    echo '</form>';

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?> 
</html>
```

Thank you very much for any help/idea out there!

Comment: You'll have to use (Asynchronous) JavaScript for that functionality.

Comment: my problem is that I am advanced in scripting html and php but I didn't ever worked with java :/

Comment: Java is something different than JavaScript ;) But it's the only way to dynamically load/show the students in the class without refreshing (submitting) the page.

Comment: javascript is best way of doing it..http://www.webtuts.in/dependent-dropdown-example-in-php-mysql/